# how to cast to an array in razor?

Tags: arrays, razor

How do I cast the below to an array in razor? currently it returns system.string[];

```
    var Users = @ViewData["arrUsers"]
```

Ive tried a few things but all return errors

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are available to write `var Users` it means that you are in code context, not HTML. So you don't need @ sign to access `ViewData`. Then you can cast as in ordinal C#.

```
@{
  var Users = (string[])ViewData["arrUsers"];
}
```

If this happens in Javascript you can do something like this. I don't think that its good to do so, but if you really need it...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var users = new Array();
        @foreach (var user in (string[])ViewData["arrUsers"])
        {@:users.push("@user");}
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am using the code in a cshtml view though, so i need the @ somwhere dont i?

Comment: Inside cshtml you can switch between HTML and C#. If you are already in C# context you don't need @.
I've modified my code snippet so you can see where to place @.

Comment: now the code is inside @{ my java function cannot see the variable can i do var Users @{...?

Comment: you think it would be better to send a deliminated string and turn that to an array in java?